# Extend array without creating new class in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using an API and receiving a array of hashes. Lets say:

```
array = client.getObjects(123) //where 123 is some collection of object ID
```

I want to add some additional attributes to the array to use later in my view, like:

`<%= array.getRequestor %> // return a string`

What is the easiest way to do this? I was thinking about creating a new class that extends array but I wanted to know can I just add a string "requestor" attribute a lot easier?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think extending `Array` would be a good idea. What should be the result of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].getRequestor`? Instead you could create a new class which only references your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending a core class is not a good idea in general, especially when the additional responsibilities you want to add in are specific to your functional domain.

6 months down the line, somebody (perhaps yourself) will be trying to debug the code and wondering why does `Array` expose a random custom method.

It would be better to explicitly define your custom view object, perhaps by using a `Struct`, eg:

```
# my_view_object.rb
class MyViewObject < Struct.new(:hash)
  def getRequestor
    # manipulate / return specific hash data
  end
end

# controller
@view_obj = MyViewObject.new(client.getObjects(123))

# view
@view_obj.hash # original hash
@view_obj.getRequestor # your custom attribute
```

Note that the intent of a `Struct` is to represent a custom data structure, not behaviour. If your custom method needs to do unrelated work, you might want to use a PORO (Plain Old Ruby Object) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that extending Array sounds like a really bad idea. I would suggest you instead wrap the array in hash of your own. For example

```
my_hash = {getRequestor: ?, array: array}
```

and then use it like

```
<%= my_hash.getRequestor %>
```

as in your example code.